# Is there a hotkey way to hide this message on the bottom right of vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

IS there a hotkey to remove this? I am not sure if disabling permanently is a good idea cause this could possibly be useful?

Comment: Does just `Escape` work for you?

Comment: I dont think esc does anything to that box. I can try in the future.

Comment: So, if I hit esc just after pop up appears, I can exit it, but if I click somewhere or do an action, the focus moves and I cant esc it anymore.. thus a need for a shortcut

Answer (score 0):

Do you have both of these entries in your `Keyboard Shortcuts`:

[image: notification hide toasts shortcuts]

One of these versions of the command `notifications.hideToasts` does not require that the notification be focused - check the `when` clauses.  Thus, <kbd>Escape</kbd> should close the notification from anywhere.  And does for me, even after typing in the editor.  If you don't have the first one shown (without the `notificationFocus` context key) for some reason - they are both defaults - add it or modify the existing one to remove the focus requirement.